# How we can get the "Fermion Parity" and "Ground states" for Majorana fermions in Bernevig's talk PiTP 2015?

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

I have two questions regarding the talk, Topological Superconductors, Majorana...and Interactions, by Bernevig in PiTP 2015.

1. How he gets the "Fermion Parity" for the ground states in the talk? for example when he talked about 2 Majorana wires and he gets the ground states $|0>$ and $f^{\dagger}|0>$, and the 6 wires system which has $f_1^{\dagger}|0>$ and $f_2^{\dagger}|0>$. You can watch it 56:24
2. I do not understand how he got the ground states for the 6 wires. Even when he considered the first term why he did not write down other combinations like $f_3^{\dagger}f_2^{\dagger}|0>$ or $f_3^{\dagger}f_1^{\dagger}|0>$( I guess the changing of fermionic operators just give a minus that is why he didn't consider them?). Also, why he did not write down $f_3^{\dagger}|0>$ as a ground state? For this part, please watch the video 58:20 to 1:01.

Bernevig's talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nywYAwKp2ac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermion parity means the parity of the number of fermions in a given state. The vacuum $\vert 0\rangle$ has zero fermions, an even number, while $\hat{f}^{\dagger}\vert 0\rangle$ has one (odd).

To obtain fermion parity you can either find the eigenvalue of the number operator $\hat{n} = \hat{f}^{\dagger}\hat{f}$, or, equivalently, of the "parity operator"
\begin{align}
\hat{P} &= -i\hat{\gamma}_1\hat{\gamma}_2 \\
&= -i(\hat{f}^{\dagger} + \hat{f})(i\hat{f}^{\dagger} - i\hat{f}) \\
&= \hat{f}^{\dagger} \hat{f}^{\dagger} -  \hat{f}^{\dagger} \hat{f} +   \hat{f} \hat{f}^{\dagger} -  \hat{f} \hat{f} \\
&= 1 - 2  \hat{f}^{\dagger} \hat{f} \\
&= 1 - 2 \hat{n}.
\end{align}

Notice how the two operators commute, so they share a common set of eigenvectors.

As for your second question, notice the structure of the energy term he was considering:

\begin{align}
\hat{E}_{12} &= \alpha(\hat{f}_1^{\dagger}\hat{f}_1 - \frac{1}{2})(\hat{f}_2^{\dagger}\hat{f}_2 - \frac{1}{2}) \\
&= \alpha (\hat{n}_1 - \frac{1}{2})(\hat{n}_2 - \frac{1}{2})
\end{align}

The eigenvalues of the terms in parenthesis are $\pm 1/2$. If only one of the terms is negative ($-1/2$), then the whole thing is $-\alpha/4$. If none or both of the terms are positive ($+1/2$), then the energy is $+\alpha/4$. In the lecture, Bernevig takes $\alpha$ to be positive, as in these systems this is a Coulomb (repulsive) interaction.

This means the ground state for $\hat{E}_{12}$ must have either of the modes $1$ or $2$ occupied, but not both. The state $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_3\vert 0\rangle$, for example, has no particles in modes $1$ and $2$, such that both terms in parenthesis will be negative, yielding a resulting energy of $+\alpha /4$, so that it is not in the groundstate manifold.

Also, notice how $\hat{E}_{12}$ does not depend on $\hat{n}_3$ and that it comutes with $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_3$. This means that if $\vert \psi \rangle$ is in the ground state manifold, then $\hat{f}^{\dagger} \vert \psi \rangle$ is also in that manifold:
\begin{align}
\hat{E}_{12} \hat{f}^{\dagger}_3 \vert \psi \rangle
&= \hat{f}^{\dagger}_3 \hat{E}_{12} \vert \psi \rangle \\
&= (-\alpha/4) \hat{f}^{\dagger}_3 \vert \psi \rangle.
\end{align}

**This means that since $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_1\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_2\vert 0 \rangle$ are ground states, then $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_1\hat{f}^{\dagger}_3\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_2\hat{f}^{\dagger}_3\vert 0 \rangle$ are ground states as well** (remember $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_i$ and $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_j$ ant commute for $i\neq j$).

Finally, when we consider both terms $E_{12}$ and $E_{23}$, we can apply the same reasoning and find the smallest contributions from both terms. The states $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_2\hat{f}^{\dagger}_3\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_1\vert 0 \rangle$ have an energy of $-\alpha/4$ for the first term, but an energy of $+\alpha/4$ for the second term, such that their total energy is zero. Likewise, the terms $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_1\hat{f}^{\dagger}_2\vert 0 \rangle$ and  $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_3\vert 0 \rangle$ have energies $+\alpha/4$ and $-\alpha/4$ for the first and second terms, repsectivelly, for a total of zero energy too. It is only the states $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_1\hat{f}^{\dagger}_3\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\hat{f}^{\dagger}_2\vert 0 \rangle$ that have contributions $-\alpha/4$ for  both terms, such that total energy is $E=-\alpha/2<0$.

**So these last states are the least energetic states and, by definition, the groundstates.**

Comment: I understand why you called the term $-i \gamma_1 \gamma_2$ as a parity( since I did not see in his lecture notes). Because $n=\frac{1-P}{2}$ so that for $n= 0 or 1$ then $P=1 or -1$.

Comment: For the second part, I think you meant if $\alpha$ be negative then $n_1= 1$ and $n_2= 1$, the Evals are $-\alpha/4$. Also if $n_1= 0$ Which the term will be negative, and $n_2= 1$ Also we can get the same for $n_1= 1$  and $n_2= 0$, with positive $\alpha$.

Comment: Can you explain these terms $f_1^{\dagger}f_3^{\dagger}|0>$ and $f_2^{\dagger}f_3^{\dagger}|0>$ are ground states? And why after adding $(\hat{f}_2^{\dagger}\hat{f}_2 - \frac{1}{2})(\hat{f}_3^{\dagger}\hat{f}_3 - \frac{1}{2}) $ to the Hamiltonian the ground states are just $f_2^{\dagger}|0>$ and $f_1^{\dagger}f_3^{\dagger}|0>$ ?

Comment: About your second comment: yes, but in the lectures Bernevig mentioned that we are considering $\alpha$ to be positive. I will clarify this in the answer. I will also address your third comment.

Comment: I expanded the post in order to answer to your doubts. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes completely!